# TeraCopy does not start copying automatically

Tags: windows, teracopy

Whenever I copy or move files using TeraCopy I have to hit the start now button. Is there a way to start it automatically?

Comment: when I do a copy/paste manually it intercedes and copies automatically.

Answer (score 3):

"Start now" issue:

**Symptoms**

When you start a copy the system stays in "Start Now" and counting down to minimize. If you miss the counting the Teracopy window will minimize without doing anything.

**Cause**

Sometimes if any transfer is interrupted Processes will not purge the queue and it will react like other instance of the program or other transfer is already running starting the countdown for user to accept another simultaneous instance of the program.

**Solution**

Delete Processes file (no extension)

1. Stop all Teracopy
2. Open Windows Explorer
3. In the address bar type `%APPDATA%/teracopy` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Delete the Processes file
5. Start any copy task for Teracopy

It should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If your TeraCopy does not run automatically when you copy-paste, please check with this step:

Run TeraCopy manually with:

```
C:/program files/TeraCopy/TeraCopy.exe
```

then in teraCopy > more > menu > options.. > check "use teracopy as default copy handler" > ok

Try again your copy or cut file.